# for loop inside array filter method in nodejs

Tags: node.js

how can i filter thiss through filter method or any loop method and then return a count object in nodejs

count: {
patient: count1,
careProvider: count2,
admin: count3,
},

reusult of this shoud be shown like this

{
"success": true,
"count": {
"patient": 434,
"careProvider": 171,
"admin": 6
}
}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please also try to share with us what have you tried so far and where did you stuck.

Comment: I agree with @PeterCsala. Please ask question in an understandable manner.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =  '{ "success": true, "count": { "patient": 434, "careProvider": 171, "admin": 6 } }'
//parsing text to json
const jsondata= JSON.parse(data);
//getting count object from the parsed json
const count = jsondata.count
//initiating the num to 0
let num = 0
//mapping from the object
Object.keys(count).map(function(key) {
  num ++
  //updating the current object value to count + num
  count[key] = 'count'+num
});


console.log(count);
```